# QGIS - filter in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter

I filtered my attribute table to get only some objects (here is my filter:

`"Code_12" BETWEEN '211' AND '243'`) but I see on my attribute table that I have selected only some objects on the objects already filtered (see screen capture). I do not know why. I need to make fragmentation calculations on my attribute tables after applying filters for each type of land covers but my results are odd so i was wondering if this could not be a reason.
Does someone know[image] ?

Comment: your expression does not fit as a filter in the attribute table, I suggest you create a new field `"Code_12_bis"`, define it numeric and populate it with `to_int ("Code_12")`, then apply the filter `"Code_12_bis">= 211 AND "Code_12_bis"<= 243`

Comment: Why not directly ` "to_int(Code_12")>= 211 AND to_int(Code_12")<= 243` ?

Comment: Your "Code_12" seem to be text field and text field doesn't always behave like numeric field with comparaison operator, try the other comments suggestion for better  results

Comment: Hi, sorry but not sure to get it with this one :  "to_int(Code_12")>= 211 AND to_int(Code_12")<= 243` it feels that the ponctuation is strange... can you rewrite it ? thanks a lot!

Comment: Also QGIS says to me "to_int" is not defined...

Comment: it should be : to_int("Code_12")>= 211 AND to_int("Code_12")<= 243

Comment: Thank you but it says that "to_int" is undefined...

Comment: If you are using the filtering option of the attribute table to_int should work as it's a oproper QGIS fonction so check your expression for typo. If you are trying to filter at the layer level (ie you use the query builder) the syntax depend on the data provider so you need to find the expected syntax (could be something like " CAST("Code_12" as integer) " or " CastToInteger("Code_12") ")

Answer (score 1):

The `Code_12` field looks textual and therefore the rules of numeric fields do not apply, so you have to transform it into an entire field, for example by adding a `virtual field` (which does not physically modify your table), steps:

1. add a virtual field Integer 32, length 9;
2. populate it with the expression `to_int ("Code_12")`;
3. apply the filter `"Code_12_bis">= 211 AND "Code_12_bis"<= 243`

### step 1:

[image]
[image]

### step 3:

[image]